# Two CSV files to one output, join and add data on column(s)

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'm working in C# (.Net 4) and I am trying to do several things:

I have 2 files ("Offline.csv","online.csv"), and I'm having those files make one "master" file (called "Attendance.csv")

Both offline.csv and online.csv contain similar data---

**My Offline.csv file has:**

```
(ID),(TimeInMin),(DateWithoutSlashes yyymmdd)
01,10,20151201
01,05,20151202
02,11,20151201
03,11,20151202
```

**My Online.csv file has**

```
(ID),(TimeInMin),(DateWithoutSlashes yyymmdd)

01,70,20151201 
02,20,20151202 
03,22,20151202
```

After my program is ran, the Attendance.csv should look something like:

```
(Same headers)
01,80,20151201
01,05,20121502 (notice the date from offline.csv, which doesn't exist in the online.csv)
02,31,20151201
03,33,20151202
```

So what I'm trying to do is:

1. Compare the data from both the offline.csv and online.csv files. If data matches on the "ID" **and** "Date" columns, add the minutes together (column 2) and put them as a row in the Attendance.csv file

However, IF the offline.csv contains rows that the online.csv doesn't have, then put all those other records into the Attendance.csv on their own. Perform the same action with the online.csv, being mindful to not duplicate minutes that were already merged together from step #1

I don't know if that all makes sense, but I hope it does :X
I have been beating my head against the wall all day with this, and I don't know what else to look at.

With all that said, here is what I have so far:

I have created my own class, called "aoitime", it looks as follows:

```
public class aoitime
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string online { get; set; }
    public string offline { get; set; }
    public string dtonline { get; set; }
    public string dtoffline { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

I then use IEnumerable in a different function, looks similar to ...

```
    IEnumerable<aoitime> together =
        from online in onlinefile
        let onlineFields = online.Split(',')
        from id in offlinefile
        let offlineFields = id.Split(',')
        where (onlineFields[0] == offlineFields[0] && onlineFields[2] == offlineFields[2]) || (!offlineFields[1].Contains(""))
        orderby onlineFields[0]

        select new aoitime
        {
            ID = onlineFields[0],
            online = onlineFields[1],
            offline = offlineFields[1],
            dtonline = onlineFields[2],
            dtoffline = offlineFields[2],
            date = onlineFields[2]
        };

    StreamWriter Attendance = new StreamWriter(destination);
    Attendance.Write("SIS_NUMBER,MINUTES,DATE" + Environment.NewLine);

    foreach (aoitime att in together)
    {
        int date = int.Parse(att.date);
        int dateonline = int.Parse(att.dtonline);
        int dateoffline = int.Parse(att.dtoffline);
        int online = int.Parse(att.online);
        int offline = int.Parse(att.offline);
        int total = (online + offline);
        Console.WriteLine("Writing total time now: "+online);
        Attendance.Write(att.ID + "," + total + "," date + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

I then tried creating another IEnumerable class spawn that looks similar to the one above, but instead using "where offlineFields[2] != onlineFields[2]" but I get unpredictable results. I just don't know where else to look or what else to do.

Please be gentle, I'm very much new to programming in general (I promise this isn't for a classroom assignment :-)

thanks so much for any advice and reading this book!

Comment: @Kosala W and greyseal96, I appreciate both your responses very very much! I love seeing different methods to approach an issue, and even more so understanding the reasoning behind them. Tomorrow when I get in, I'm going to work more on the program to get it going and tested (this is of course the final piece of the puzzle!)

Comment: @Kosala-w and greyseal96, if I could, I'd select both of your suggestions as answers. I am going to select Kosala's as the answer because he did post first, and it was ultimately the direction I went in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. I wrote this code, so hopefully you will be able to learn something from it.

First you only need one entity class for this. Note the ToString method. You will see how it's used later.

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TimeInMinutes { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Id, TimeInMinutes, Date);
    }
}
```

Now the code to parse your files and create the new file. Read my comments in the code.

```
    var onlineEntries = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\online.txt");//read online file
    var validOnlineEntries = onlineEntries.Where(l => !l.Contains("(")); //remove first line
    var onlineRecords = validOnlineEntries.Select(r => new Attendance()
    {
        Id = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]),
        TimeInMinutes = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]),
        Date = r.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)[2],
    }).ToList();//popultae Attendance class

    var offlineEntries = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\offline.txt"); //read online file
    var validOfflineEntries = offlineEntries.Where(l => !l.Contains("(")); //remove first line
    var offlineRecords = validOfflineEntries.Select(r => new Attendance()
    {
        Id = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]),
        TimeInMinutes = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]),
        Date = r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2],
    }).ToList();//popultae Attendance class

    var commonRecords = (from n in onlineRecords
                        join f in offlineRecords on new {n.Date, n.Id } equals new {f.Date, f.Id} //if Date and Id are equal
                        select new { n.Id, TimeInMinutes = (n.TimeInMinutes + f.TimeInMinutes), n.Date }).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Distinct().ToList(); //add Online and Off line time

    var newRecords = commonRecords.Select(r => new Attendance()
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        TimeInMinutes = r.TimeInMinutes,
        Date = r.Date,
    }); //Poulate attendance again. So we can call toString method

    onlineRecords.AddRange(offlineRecords); //merge online and offline
    var recs = onlineRecords.Distinct().Where(r => !newRecords.Any(o => o.Date == r.Date && o.Id == r.Id)).ToList(); //remove already added items from merged online and offline collection
    newRecords.AddRange(recs);//add filtered merged collection to new records
    newRecords = newRecords.OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();//order new records by id

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\newFile.txt", newRecords.Select(l => l.ToString()).ToList()); //write new file.
```

Comment: I think that that only gets OP halfway there.  Per OP's requirements:
    Compare the data from both the offline.csv and online.csv files. If
    data matches on the "ID" and "Date" columns, add the minutes 
    together (column 2) and put them as a row in the Attendance.csv file

    **However, IF the offline.csv contains rows that the online.csv doesn't 
    have, _then put all those other records into the Attendance.csv on 
    their own_. _Perform the same action with the online.csv, being mindful 
    to not duplicate minutes that were already merged together from 
    step #1_**

Comment: @greyseal96 You are right. I missed that part. Added a few more lines to the code. That should get him there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I noticed I gave small "IDs", instead of using their official ones in this example. The IDs are actually pretty long ( they look like 12300000789), so I modified your example so that the ID in the class represented a string, and modified the function appropriately to reflect the change. Other than that, I added ".ToList();" at the end of the newrecords var and all went well. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add this as an answer, I am selecting @Kosala-w's suggestion as an answer. My code now looks very identical to what he posted, except I modified the ID to a string format because the integers used for the IDs are pretty lenghty.

I thank both people who answered this question, and I appreciate the SO community! Have a good day :-)

```
public class Attendance
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int TimeInMinutes { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Id, TimeInMinutes, Date);
    }
    }
```

I also have more rows that I have to handle in the Attendance sheet than I stated in my original question (I didn't worry about those because I wasn't concerned that I'd have a hard time getting what I needed.)

Anyway, the code below is what I used, again, thanks Kosala.

```
    private void createAttendance()
    {
        try
        {
            txtStatus.ResetText();
            txtStatus.Text += "Creating Attendance file. Please wait.";

            string destination = (@"C:\asdf\Attendance.csv");
            barStatus.Caption = "Processing Attendance file. Please wait.";
            if (File.Exists(destination))
                File.Delete(destination);

            var validOnlineEntries = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\asdf\online.csv");//read online file
                                                                              //var validOnlineEntries = onlineEntries.Where(l => !l.Contains("(")); //remove first line
            var onlineRecords = validOnlineEntries.Select(r => new Attendance()
            {
                Id = (r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + ",202" + "," + txtYear.Text),
                TimeInMinutes = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]),
                Date = r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2],
            }).ToList();//populate Attendance class

            var validOfflineEntries = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\asdf\offline.csv"); //read online file
                                                                                 //var validOfflineEntries = offlineEntries.Where(l => !l.Contains("(")); //remove first line
            var offlineRecords = validOfflineEntries.Select(r => new Attendance()
            {
                Id = (r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + ",202" + "," + txtYear.Text),
                TimeInMinutes = int.Parse(r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]),
                Date = r.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2],
            }).ToList();//populate Attendance class

            var commonRecords = (from n in onlineRecords
                                 join f in offlineRecords on new { n.Date, n.Id } equals new { f.Date, f.Id } //if Date and Id are equal
                                 select new { n.Id, TimeInMinutes = (n.TimeInMinutes + f.TimeInMinutes), n.Date }).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Distinct().ToList(); //add Online and Off line time

            var newRecords = commonRecords.Select(r => new Attendance()
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                TimeInMinutes = r.TimeInMinutes,
                Date = r.Date,
            }).ToList(); //Populate attendance again. So we can call toString method

            onlineRecords.AddRange(offlineRecords); //merge online and offline
            var recs = onlineRecords.Distinct().Where(r => !newRecords.Any(o => o.Date == r.Date && o.Id == r.Id)).ToList(); //remove already added items from merged online and offline collection
            newRecords.AddRange(recs);//add filtered merged collection to new records
            newRecords = newRecords.OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();//order new records by id

            StreamWriter Attendance = new StreamWriter(destination);
            //Attendance.Write("SIS_NUMBER,SCHOOL_CODE,SCHOOL_YEAR,ABSENCE_DATE,ABSENCE_REASON1,ABSENCE_REASON2,MINUTES_ATTEND,NOTE,ABS_FTE1,ABS_FTE2" + Environment.NewLine);
            Attendance.Write("SIS_NUMBER,SCHOOL_CODE,SCHOOL_YEAR,MINUTES_ATTEND,ABSENCE_DATE,ABSENCE_REASON2,ABSENCE_REASON1,NOTE,ABS_FTE1,ABS_FTE2" + Environment.NewLine);
            Attendance.Dispose();
            File.AppendAllLines(destination, newRecords.Select(l => l.ToString()).ToList()); //write new file.

            Convert_CSV_To_Excel();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            barStatus.Caption = ("ERROR: "+ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I plan to do some more fine tuning, but this sure got me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I'd do is define a simpler class to hold your aoitimes.  For example:

```
public class aoitime
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int TimeInMinutes { get; set; }
    public string DateWithoutSlashes { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you'll want to parse the string from the csv file into that class.  I figure that that's an implementation detail that you can probably figure out on your own.  If not, leave a comment and I can post more details.

Next, the tricky part is that you want not only a join, but you want the exceptions as well.  The join logic is fairly simple:

```
var matches = from offline in offlineItems
              join online in onlineItems
              on 
              new {offline.ID, offline.DateWithoutSlashes} equals 
              new {online.ID, online.DateWithoutSlashes}
              select new aoitime
              {
                  ID = offline.ID,
                  TimeInMinutes = offline.TimeInMinutes + online.TimeInMinutes,
                  DateWithoutSlashes = offline.DateWithoutSlashes
              };
```

(Notice there that you're using anonymous objects in the "ON" join condition). But the hard part is how to get the exceptions.  LINQ is set up to do inner joins or equijoins, but I'm not sure about outer joins.  At least I haven't seen it.

So one solution might be to use the LINQ join to get the matches and then another LINQ query to get those that don't match and then combine those two collections and write them out to a file.

Another solution might be to go back to basics and do the iteration logic yourself.  LINQ is just elegant iteration logic and if it doesn't do what you need it to do, you might need to do it yourself.

For example, let's say that you have your collection of online and offline items and you want to iterate through them and do the comparison:

```
List<aoitime> offlineItems = <some method that produces this list>
List<aoitime> onlineItems = <some method that produces this list>
List<aoitime> attendanceItems = new List<aoitime>();
//For simplicity, assuming that you have the same number of elements in each list
for (int i = 0; i < offlineItems.Count; i++)
{
    aoitime offline = offlineItems[i];
    aoitime online = onlineItems[i];
    if(offline.ID == online.ID && offline.DateWithoutSlashes = online.DateWithoutSlashes)
    {
        //Create your new object and add it to the attendance items collection.
    }
    else
    {
        //Process the exceptions and add them individually to the attendance items collection.
    }
}
```

So you do the iteration and processing yourself and have control over the whole process.  Does that make sense?  If not, let me know in a comment and I can add more.

Comment: thank you for your help, I appreciate being able to see it a little more simplified than what I was going for initially, and I realize that your suggestion would work just as well. Thanks again!